# Euclidean division exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I faced the following problem in a previous abstract algebra session in my university:
Let $\omega$ be a non-zero real number and n be a non-zero natural integer both supposed to be fixed. Calculate the remainder of the Euclidean division of the polynomial $(\cos{\omega}+X\sin{\omega}) ^n$ by $X^2 +1$.

I tried to expand $(\cos{\omega}+X\sin{\omega}) ^n$ but it didn't look helpful for me. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write the reminder $aX+b$. You have

$$P(X) = (\cos \omega + \sin\omega X)^n =Q(X)(X^2+1) +aX+b.$$

Substitute in this equation $X$ by $i$. You get 
$$e^{in \omega} = ai+b.$$ Substitute now $X$ by $-i$. You get

$$e^{-in \omega} = -ai+b$$

Solving in $a,b$ you finally get $b =\cos n\omega$ and $a = \sin n\omega$.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same answer as mathcounterexamples.net's answer, but it's a slightly different explanation and thought process, which seems to me to be slightly more natural (though I did upvote mce.net's answer). Hence I'll give my thought process on seeing this question.

We can calculate the remainder on division by a polynomial $f\in k[x]$ by working in the ring $k[x]/(f)$, since the remainder of a polynomial $a$ on division by $f$ is the unique representative of $a$ in $k[x]/(f)$ of degree less than the degree of $f$.

Then recognize that $\Bbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)\cong \Bbb{C}$ via $X\mapsto i$.
Thus $(\cos \omega +X\sin \omega)^n\mapsto (e^{i\omega})^n=e^{i\omega n} = \cos(n\omega) + i \sin(n\omega)$. Thus the remainder on division by $X^2+1$ must be $\cos(n\omega)+X\sin(n\omega)$.

Comment: Note that algebraic concerns alone cannot tell you whether you should use $X \mapsto \mathrm{i}$ or $X \mapsto -\mathrm{i}$ (since algebra doesn't distinguish Galois conjugates).  mathcounterexamples.net does both.

Comment: @EricTowers That's what confuses me so much about mathcounterexamples.net's answer. There's absolutely no reason to do both, since it doesn't matter which isomorphism with $\Bbb{C}$ you choose. You'll get the same answer either way.

Comment: Since algebra can't tell the difference, *both* specializations give (simultaneously) valid equations.  We get an equation for $b+ \mathrm{i} a$ and its conjugate $b - \mathrm{i} a$, exactly as we should since the action taking $\mathrm{i}$ to $-\mathrm{i}$ is conjugation.  (If the LHS had been *real*, the two equations would be redundant, again as expected, since $\mathbb{R}$ is fixed by this action.)

Comment: @EricTowers, but you don't need both, since we've already fixed an isomorphism to $\Bbb{C}$. The fact that $b+ia=e^{in\omega}$ is already enough to figure out what $a$ and $b$ are, since we know how to expand $e^{in\omega}$ in the $1,i$ basis for $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: ... or you've had $\sin \theta = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} - \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\theta}}{2\mathrm{i}}$ beaten into you so hard that when you try both substitutions in your head you realize you can immediately solve for $a$ and $b$ in sines and cosines entirely algebraically, that is, without having to know an additional obscure analysis fact: Euler's identity.    Notice: I'm not claiming mathcounterexample.net's answer is better or worse than yours.  I'm only responding to your line "since frankly I don't follow several aspects ..." with how my head justified his manipulations.

Comment: @EricTowers That last comment actually helped me follow his thought process a bit better. I certainly read his answer and was like, why bother making both substitutions. That said, I'd still quibble with the claim that Euler's identity is an obscure analysis fact. Not to mention that it's entirely equivalent to the pair of facts that $\cos\theta = (e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})/2$ and $\sin\theta = (e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})/(2i)$. Also I didn't take your comment to imply that you thought my answer was worse or something, I just continued to fail to see the point of using both isomorphisms.

Comment: My algebra brain has the knee-jerk fact that $\{a+b, a-b\}$ has a very fast solution method.  But my algebra brain spends zero time applying analysis facts because those tend to require all sorts of structure that is missing in the algebra I frequently face.  When I saw him go to the second specialization, my algebra brain said, "ah, to solve trivially for $a$ and $b$", and then the analysis part of my brain (from the back of the room, somewhere) said "hey, that's almost sine and cosine" (and then went back to doing whatever...).  <continued>

Comment: ... so the chain of thoughts is not "I can get sine and cosine if I use both specializations"; it's "now we do all the specializations we can to get a system of equations, which, oho!, we can solve immediately to get, ..., hunh, sines and cosines."

Comment: @EricTowers Fair enough, I follow the thought process now I think, I've edited my initial comments in my answer to reflect that.

Comment: My interpretation of @mathcounterexamples.net thought process is: the equation must be true for any $X$. Now pick both $i$ and $-i$, which leads to the desired result. The same method applies for polynomial factorization, partial fraction decomposition, Taylor expansion, etc. No need for ring theory and quotient rings, just high school math. It has its elegance. I also like the ring approach though.